# Непонятный результат при вычитании: двенадцать цифр после запятой

Tags: perl

Прокомментируйте такой момент, а то понять не могу. Моя железная логика пасует перед битово-байтовой. Есть число "А" и "В". "А" - десятичное, то есть две циферки после запятой. "В" - целое. Вычитаю "В" из "А" - получается десятичное, но циферок после запятой - двенадцать! Откуда, если в базе данных нигде не фигурирует даже одна тысячная?  Что это, глюк какой-то? Будут какие нибудь предположения? Результат получается типа: 784.550000000001...

Answer (score 5):

Это не глюк, это IEEE 754. Смотри статью «Числа с плавающей запятой и их особенности» (http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:v-8g3aRju-8J:xpoint.ru/know-how/Articles/FloatingPointNumbers).

Comment: Ссылка не работает, пардон....

Comment: @Asid, какой-то глюк, поправил, чтоб работало.